# edit content of anchor tag

Tags: css, anchor, edit

I have been trying to edit the content of anchor tag, but I don't understand where I am going wrong. Here is the code that I need to edit

```
<div class="entry-content" itemprop="description">
<a class="button color-simple" href="http://techaccessok.org/person/std-speaker-2/" rel="bookmark">Nice to meet you!</a>
</div>
```

Below is my solution that I have been trying

```
.entry-content > a {
content : "My Presentation";
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can only add content via CSS, not change it. At least not that way. `content` only works with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements anyway

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

Comment: So how do I change the content from "NICE TO MEET YOU" to "YOUR PRESENTATION"

Comment: With JavaScript

Comment: Javascript? CSS really should only be used to change the styles of the document not content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to produce the effect by using [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and tweaking a combination of `margins` `padding` and `z-index`

**This is pure CSS but hacky at best.**

*This will need to be tweaked further to match your current content well.*

**Working example:**

```css
.entry-content a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 0; /* needs to be modified */
  color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
}

.entry-content a:after {
  content: "My Presentation";
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -15px; /* use the same size as your font */
  color: red;
}

.entry-content a:hover:after {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content" itemprop="description">
  <a class="button color-simple" href="http://techaccessok.org/person/std-speaker-2/" rel="bookmark">Nice to meet you!</a>
</div>
```